# Sencha Architect localstorage not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am brand new to Sencha Touch/Architect and trying to create my first store.  I have the following items setup:

Store

```
Ext.define('InkStudio.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'InkStudio.model.activityLog'
    ],

    config: {
        data: {
            entryID: 1,
            name: 'First',
            event: 'First event'
        },
        model: 'InkStudio.model.activityLog',
        storeId: 'MyStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            uniqueID: 'entryID'
        }
    }
});
```

Model

```
    Ext.define('InkStudio.model.activityLog', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        identifier: 'uuid',
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'entryID',
                type: 'auto'
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'event',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Then I have a button with the following for a test.  The button is working and I receive both "Success" messages but the data never actually shows up in the store when I look at it or cat the file for it.

```
var store=Ext.getStore('MyStore');
if(store.add({name: "KITTY", event: "Clicked on the register"})){
    console.log("Successfully added");
}else{
    console.log("Failed to add");   
}
if(store.sync()){ 
    console.log("Successfully synced");
}else
{
    console.log("Failed to sync");
}
```

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data` config is used only when you want fixed information in your view. The correct is:

```
Ext.define('InkStudio.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'InkStudio.model.activityLog'
    ],

    config: {
        model: 'InkStudio.model.activityLog',
        storeId: 'MyStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'my-store-id'
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT** The store methods are async, so you need to use the options to actually see the changes.

```
var record = Ext.create('InkStudio.model.activityLog');
...
//first we load our store.
store.load({
  callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    console.log('Store loaded...');
    //then we can add records
    store.add(record);
    store.sync({
      success: function(batch, options) {
        console.log("Record saved...");
      },
      failure : function(batch, options) {
        console.log("Error!");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sergio, thank you for the response. I had the data in there as a pre-existing data test per a tutorial I found. I have removed the data and tried everything again but still nothing shows up.  Basically to test it I've got everything as setup and then I'm pushing the button to trigger the code and then looking at my files for "KITTY" to show up in the store but it doesn't.

Comment: You also need to change in your proxy from `uniqueID` to just `id`. This property name don't exists and without an id your localstorage will not work.

Comment: Ok, I removed the uniqueID: 'entryID' and changed it to id: 'id' and there was no change, I also tried id: 'entryID' and that had no effect either :(

Comment: Ok, so I've apparently got the working code now as I've made it so that it does the sync and then alerts to the count. Every time I hit the button the count seems to go up. The problem is that this data doesn't seem to be actually getting saved anywhere.  How can I make it retain these additions?

Comment: I checked again your code. The manipulation of the store is async, so you need to use callback functions that will be executed when the job is done. See my answer edit.

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up with, as I'm new to it all I didn't fully understand localStorage. I was looking for results in my files instead of in chromes resources.  I now see that I have dozens of results from my repeated tests that I thought were somehow failing.  Thanks again for all the help!